# Java annotation to transform a json field

Tags: java, json, validation, annotations, data-formatters

I am trying to come up with an interface that has pretty non-standard way of representing fields as it is fed from a legacy system, this interface seems to require some custom validations + transformations such as

- Truncating a string value beyond specified length (example : in some cases truncate the string beyond 25th character, in some other cases truncate beyond 15th character)
- Validate that a string date field is of format `YYYMMDD` and transforming it to a date field of `yyyy-MM-dd` format in the setter

How do I come up with custom annotations that can do this using `@interface`? I was able to find `@Constraint(validatedBy=someclass.class)` but there doesn't seem to be something to transform the data (or sorry if I haven't looked enough).. Any pointers on this would be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. In general, the idea would be: you define a bunch of annotations, and then you have a central component that manages your "data objects"; and that component uses reflection to get the list of annotations on your fields; to then do the "right" thing; like validate data before updating a "data object".

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you just use the "transformed" DataType in your Jackson annotated objects, for example:

```
 private TransformedData data;
```

Then you configure Jackson with a deserializer that accepts a String and returns a "TransformedData" object.  When Jackson is trying to fill in your data field, it will notice that it needs conversion and call your deserializer.